# Pandas write to CSV specify dtype

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Is there a way to prevent write a Pandas dataframe as a CSV without converting numbers that are formatted as strings to numerics?

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d=pd.DataFrame(index=['07000','07001','07002'], data=[1,2,3], columns=['Value'])
>>> d.index.name='Zipcode'
>>> d
         Value
Zipcode       
07000        1
07001        2
07002        3
>>>
```

I can confirm that my index is not a numeric:

```
>>> print str(d.index.dtype)
object
>>>
```

But when I write to csv using `d.to_csv('MyFile.csv')` the index is converted to an integer and I lose the leading 0. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the zeroes are lost when writing to csv? I replicated your results and examine my csv file, and all of the zeroes are there. My guess is that they are lost by whatever program you then use to read the new file.

Comment: Agreed.  I replicated the code.  When I open the csv file in a txt editor, I get the leading zeros.  If you open the file in a spreadsheet program (or read it back into a pandas dataframe) the zeros are dropped at that point.

Comment: Ah thank you. So the issue is actually when I read in the csv not when I write it. And I can specify the dtype when reading in a csv, so problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with the `d.to_csv('MyFile.csv')`. I have all the zeros in my .csv file by running your code.

If you use `d1 = pd.read_csv('MyFile.csv', index_col=0)`, the leading zeros will be dropped in the `d1`.